# iFrame Not Downsizing

Tags: iframe, joomla, iframe-resizer

I am trying to use this site in an iFrame with [iFrame-Resizer version 4.2.2](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer):

https://dealertile.com/

However, I cannot get a consistent sizing of the iFrame. To begin with, I have to use custom 'heightCalculationMethod' or the iFrame only renders to 150px height:

- bodyOffset = 150px height.
- bodyScroll = Correct initial height. Grows on page changes, but does not shrink.
- documentElementOffset = 150px height.
- documentElementScroll = Correct initial height. Grows on page changes, but does not shrink.
- max = Correct initial height. Grows on page changes, but does not shrink.
- min = 150px height.
- grow = Correct initial height. Grows on page changes, but does not shrink.
- lowestElement = Correct initial height. Grows on page changes, but does not shrink.
- taggedElement = 0px height.

You can see my demo iFrame here: https://dealertile.com/demo/

Can someone help me figure out why the iFrame is not shrinking and only growing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this always come down to a CSS bug, the most common issue is setting a percentage height on an element

Comment: This seems very odd, but it fixed the problem. Fortunately, I had some code I no longer used, but I had a bunch of "height: 100%" elements that had to be removed. I'm not sure why it's the issue, but a lot of popups, photo galleries, etc. use this type of CSS for overlays.

Comment: @David are you, by chance, a current Joomla user/developer?

Comment: I’m afraid not, looked at it briefly about a decade ago.